# QR Image Not Shown JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a QR code generator project. UI is ready, but regarding the functionality when I press the button, it does not show the QR image.

I checked the console, there were no errors. Also, I actually saw QR image once or twice, but they disappeared in less than second when I pressed the button. How can I solve this issue?

HTML /JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>QR Code Generator</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
      <div class="form">
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="qrText" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL" />
          <input id="size" type="number" name="size" placeholder="Size (px)" />
          <div id="imgBox">
            <img src="" id="qrImage" />
          </div>
          <button id="btn" onclick="generateQR()">Generate QR Code</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      let imgBox = document.getElementById("imgBox");
      let qrImage = document.getElementById("qrImage");
      let qrText = document.getElementById("qrText");
      let qrSize = document.getElementById("size");
      let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

      function generateQR() {
        qrImage.src =
          "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" +
          qrText.value;
        imgBox.classList.add("show-img");
        if (!qrText.value || qrText.value === "") {
          alert("Please Enter URL");
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: rgb(255, 179, 64);
}

.wrapper {
  background: whitesmoke;
  max-width: 700px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.wrapper h1{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form :where(input, button){
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;;
}

.form :where(button){
    background: brown;
    color: wheat;
    font-size: large;
    border-style: none;
}

#imgBox{
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

#imgBox img{
    width: 100%;
}
#imgBox.show-img{
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: <button id="btn" onclick="generateQR()" type="button">Copy Me</button>
add type = button in this button element and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Issue is solved, thx for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your button refreshes the page onclick, which is a default behavior since you didn't specify the `type` attribute.

When you don't specify the `type` attribute, it falls by default to `type="submit"` which refreshes the page upon click (after submitting the data; which is not what you're doing here).

Adding an attribute `type="button"` to your button element will solve the problem.